# ScrollView with Buttons inside, no response until second click on any button inside

Tags: android, scrollview

I've been a couple of days trying to solve this thing but I can't figure it out. The problem is, simple activity, with simple layout, ScrollView -> LinearLayout -> and a lot of buttons inside the layout (within the scroll content). Everything works just fine, but one tricky thing. When I click a button, let's say at the top of the scroll content and immediately scroll down to the bottom of the content and click another button there, nothing happens until I click a second time and all comes to normal again. This can be reproduced anytime and it's code independent (I've tried more than 20 scenarios). I don't have much experience in Android yet, but looks like the scroll listener stops the onClick listener or something like that. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

PD. If I programmatically do a `scrollTo()`, instead of manual scroll with my fingers, everything works just fine and the click responds at first touch. It's simply overwhelming me.

Comment: @esenian: Create a sample project that demonstrates the problem. Upload that project somewhere (e.g., as a ZIP file). Post a link to that here, in a comment prefixed with @CommonsWare so I know you posted it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've uploaded a project here http://www.megaupload.com/?d=U69RRBAW Really simple, layout, no actions, just press Button 1, scrolldown and press Button 14. You'll see what I mean (no orange frame on the button till second click). Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @esenian: MegaUpload says the file is unavailable. Perhaps posting your Activity class Java source and the layout XML file (if there is one) will be sufficient, either by editing your question, or perhaps by using http://gist.github.com or similar "pastebin" services.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry for inconvenience. I've used github http://gist.github.com/656821 to upload main activity and layout. As I said very simple code without functionality but I think it shows what I mean. Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is behaving normally.

When you start scrolling, the `ScrollView` will claim touch events until you stop touching the screen for a bit. In Android 2.2, you will know when scrolling is deemed complete, because the scrollbar on the right will fade away.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. So I asume there is no option to reduce the time while scrollview is claming touch events once it stops scrolling (at leat visually)...? I know it's not much time, maybe 0,5 seconds but sill anoying. If there was a way it would be great. Anyway thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @esenian: "So I asume there is no option to reduce the time while scrollview is claming touch events once it stops scrolling (at leat visually)...?" -- not that I am aware of. Bear in mind that a `ScrollView` of a list of `Buttons` is not a technique you will see many production applications use.

Comment: Sure you're right and again thank you, I thought this was the approach for the new YouTube app from google. It seems to have an horizontalscrollview populated with buttons simulating "scrolling tabs". I've made it work and look pretty much the same but the issue with the click lag was annoying. Now I see that the app itself has also the same laggy behaviour with this so that my approach must be quite close. It's nice in my opinion. I'll try to see the scrollview code to see if I can override what controls this time. Really thank you man.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
I disagree that it's a fading scrollbar issue. If you disable the fading, the same thing happens.

Tried several approaches in themes.xml:

```
<item name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade">100</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">100</item>
<item name="android:fadeScrollbars">true</item>
```

But nothing helped.
It seems that it's a system thing with scrollViews.
This might help to see what's going on:

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(scrollState == 0) Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
    }
  });
}
```

But that (unfortunately) doesn't help in overcoming the problem - but rather explaining it.

NOTE: this only happens if you use ScrollView. ListView doesn't have this problem.

Anyone has another idea ?

Comment: Maybe you've found a solution for this? It looks like it's related to scroll acceleration (harder swipe action will result in longer delay even if scroll stops immediately at the very top/bottom), but I have no idea how to workaround it.

Answer (score 1):

I got a situation like this. I have a ExpandableListView, it just behaves normally. When I rotate the cellphone to horizontal, and rotate back, then some items in one group of the ExpandableListView will not responding for click event. Unless I scroll the list view, or click the group item of these items, the event will dispatch to the items I clicked previously, and perform the click listener codes correctly.

This happened both in android 2.3 and 4.0...

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix this by overriding onScrollChanged, then sending the ScrollView a MotionEvent via OnTouchEvent when the bounds are reached to simulate a user touch.

It's the hackiest, dirtiest programming I can imagine, but it works ok in my application. This app is for phones running 2.2 only, and this bug needed to be fixed somehow.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Edit: This problem is only in 2.2 btw, they've fixed it in 2.3, and it wasn't an issue in 2.1.