# Children of ScrollView doesn't respond to first touch if ScrollView is still "accelerating"

Tags: android, interface, scrollview

So, I have some various controls with OnClickListeners stacked in a ScrollView and I've noticed that sometimes those controls does not react to touch, which is quite annoying and can confuse end user. The other thing I've noticed, that this is happening if scrollbar is still "visible", which means that ScrollView is still accelerating and usually happens when I swipe harder and it hits bottom or top (in these cases fade delay can be up to 5 seconds). No setting I've tried solves this (delaybeforefade, fadeduration, fadescrollbars), so I guess the roots of this problem is deeper.

Does anyone else faced this annoyance and maybe found a valid solution or workaround? Is it possible to stop ScrollView acceleration as soon as it hits top/bottom?

Now that I think about it... maybe it would be easiest just to ignore fling in subclassed ScrollView (in my case I could live with that)?

This is actually the same problem as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061118/problem-in-a-scrollview-with-buttons-inside-no-response-until-second-click-on-an), which, unfortunately, hasn't received any proper solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my application for the same condition, but mine is working fine.

Its on 2.1