# AutoScroll Text inside Textview

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, spannablestring

I need help to resolve my issue that I want to move ScrollView which contains text (ClickableSpan text) in TextView. I highlighted the Spannable text (Done).How can I achieve to move scroll while highlighted text both together?
Please see the image link which clear further my question
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IheHSt8sxd7y0BN9kr_pP0W3cxOompec

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        int end = spanString.indexOf("﴾", startAyat) + 1;
        spanText.setSpan(new myClickableSpan(i), startAyat, end, 0);
        startAyat = end;
    }
```

XMLLayout

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvArabicQuran"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: you question is not clear , you need to auto scroll textview?

Comment: I have scrollview i need to move scrollview while highlighted text inside textview. I have long text thats why i use scrollview . I have done highlighted  text (one by one ) inside texview using spannable text and spannale clicks. Screen hide highlighted text need to move scroll to show further text

Comment: okay same issue like ? -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061118/scrollview-with-buttons-inside-no-response-until-second-click-on-any-button-ins

Comment: No please see the image link. it will clear what i need                               https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IheHSt8sxd7y0BN9kr_pP0W3cxOompec

Comment: okay thanks let me check

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IheHSt8sxd7y0BN9kr_pP0W3cxOompec

Comment: post your whole xml code in your question because everything is ok then why scrollview not work

Comment: XML already posted i need some logic of code to move scrollview . I dnt know on the basis of highlighted text.. i not yet wrote scrollview move code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164874/discussion-between-adilhusen-and-user1159258).

Comment: check with updated ans

Comment: did you get with?

Comment: yes answer satisfied and working thank you for your brilliant help.

Comment: okay do right tick answer bro

Answer (score 2):

You need to scroll some specific text  from TextView then first of all you need to get line index where you want to scroll

**for find line using text**

```
int offset=myString.indexOf("search string");
int line = tvArabicQuran.getLayout().getLineForOffset(offset);
```

**scroll to specific line**

```
sv.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int y = tvArabicQuran.getLayout().getLineTop(line); // e.g. I want to scroll to line
        sv.scrollTo(0, y);
    }
});
```